# Zend action helper redirector

Tags: php, zend-framework, actionviewhelper

How to redirect in models or not in contrroler? use standart zend redirector helper

```
$redirector = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();
$redirector->gotoUrl('/');
```

Comment: Why the down votes? No question, redirecting in models is a Bad Thing (tm), but does the OP need to penalized simply for asking?

Answer (score 5):

You should never redirect from a model, redirection should only occur in controllers.  Models should be designed in a black box mannor, independant of the controller.